# How to convert an image to a base64 string?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, image, base64

I'm trying to convert an image to a base64 string.

I am using an Html code to get the input image from the user. The image is of type file. In my Javascript program I made the following call and received a string that looked similar to a base64,

```
var name = document.getElementById("client_image").src;
```

where "client_image" is the id of the file in html.

My problem is that when I pass image to post to the server I get a FormatException thrown saying that I do not have a proper base64 string.

Anyway I can fix this? Also, is there any other way I can post an uploaded image to the server?

Please Help.

Comment: What does C# have to do with this?

Comment: i am using c# to post the image to the server

Comment: Your question doesn't have a mention of C#, so even if you're using it outside the scope of this question, it's irrelevant here (not a big deal, just explaining)

Comment: thats true, sorry about that

Comment: I have tried all the answers that were suggest for the other question and none of them worked for me , that is the reason why i asked my own question. I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time now and was wondering if someone can give me an answer different to the answers posted to the other question . thank you